# How to setup a login page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to render my views and what not. This all works fine. But I now need to create a login page.

Normally my base layout has a top navbar and a side menu on the left and loads the body on the right side of the menu. Just like a typical admin dashboard: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/

Now obviously when you're not logged in then you shouldn't be able to see the left menu and the top nav bar.

I could "hide" them with a `ng-if="$root.isLoggedIn"`.  Actually, that's what I have now. But when you load the page then you see all the menus for a split second. It then flashes away because that's when AngularJS is done loading and parsing the DOM.

Not really a pretty view if you ask me.

So how do others solve this problem? Is there a way to have a login page that uses a different base layout?

Comment: Look up `ng-cloak`. Also, reverse the logic behind that `ng-if`. Hide the menu by default, only show it if logged in.

Comment: ng-show/ng-hide can be turned off by disabling css styles in Safari.  
ng-if removes it from the dom completely so I would stick with ng-if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [ngCloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Description in the docs:

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading